# How to create Snippet for .sublime-snippet file?

Tags: sublimetext2, code-snippets, sublimetext3

**How to create Snippet for .sublime-snippet file?? ON SUBLIME-TEXT 2**

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
    <tabTrigger>${1}</tabTrigger>
    ]]></content>

    <tabTrigger>tabt</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.sublime-snippet</scope>
    <description>Snippet sublime</description>
</snippet>
```

**this snippet code does not work for sublime.snippet file**

Comment: The scope of snippet files is `test.xml` Note that the snippet will also be available via tab trigger for all xml files.

Comment: **thanks,, now it works!!**
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
    <tabTrigger>${1}</tabTrigger>
    ]]></content>

    <tabTrigger>tabt</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.xml</scope>
    <description>Snippet sublime</description>
</snippet>

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the snippet is `text.xml` typo in my comment, sorry about that. You can identify the scope of the file by pressing `ctrl+alt+shift+p` in Windows and Linux or `cmd+alt+p` in OS X.